# Where can I download the virtual machine for windows server 2008

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, windows-server-2008, virtual-machine

I want to setup VM for Dynamic CRM 2011.

and As CRM 2011 supports win server 2008 so, i need VM for this.

I have windows 7 PC and VM will be executed on this machine.

Please share any link where Win server 2008 VM available and it can be run on windows 7 machine ?

Can we run [server 2008 VM link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16572) VM on windows 7 machine ??? any alternative to do this ?

Comment: I have a VM all set with CRM 2011, may be sometime i upload that on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup CRM on my Windows 7 in the following way:

First you should have `Windows 7 64-bit`

1. Download and Install Virtual Box
2. Install Windows Server 2008
3. Then Start Windows Server 2008 on VM
4. Install Sql Sever 2008 and Sharepoint 2010
5. Install CRM 2011

`I followed below link to setup CRM VM on my Windows 7 64-bit:`

LINK: http://axforum.info/forums/showthread.php?t=34414

Comment: Can this do on win 7 32 machine ? Can we run server 2008 VM link VM on windows 7 32 machine ??? any alternative to do this ?

Comment: @user3711357 I am afraid you can't crm 2011 architecture is 64bit

Comment: But, we use virtual box 32 bit on windows 7 32 machine and load windows 2008 server OS 64 bit on it. and move further to setup CRM and related softwares. will it work by this way OR Another thing, can i use  server 2008 VM link (link is as follow- http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16572) VM on windows 7 32 machine through virtual box or any way ???

Comment: @user3711357 I am not sure, have'nt tried that yet. May be someone else had experimented this. try google for some articles to find out answers.